# itext7: style “display:block;” is invalid in <strong>

Tags: itext7

Please help me, thank

hello.html :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            body {font-family: sans-serif;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1><div><strong style="display:block;color:green">Hello</strong>World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

java code:

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("target/hello.pdf", new WriterProperties().setFullCompressionMode(true));
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream("html/hello.html"), writer, properties);
```

output hello.pdf :
 [code "style='display:block;'" is invalid in tag 'strong'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKewI.png)

output Chrome:
 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDXHt.png)

Answer (score 4):

By default iText maps `<strong>` tag to `<span>`'s tag worker and css applier. You should override this behaviour.

Create your custom tag worker factory:

```
class StrongTagWorkerFactory extends DefaultTagWorkerFactory {
@Override
public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
    if (tag.name().equals(TagConstants.STRONG)) {
        if (CssConstants.BLOCK.equals(tag.getStyles().get(CssConstants.DISPLAY))) {
            return new DivTagWorker(tag, context);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Pass its instance as a parameter to `ConverterProperties` instance you use to convert the html:

```
converterProperties.setCssApplierFactory(new StrongCssApplierFactory());
```

Create your custom css applier factory:

```
class StrongCssApplierFactory extends DefaultCssApplierFactory {
@Override
public ICssApplier getCustomCssApplier(IElementNode tag) {
    if (tag.name().equals(TagConstants.STRONG)) {
        if (CssConstants.BLOCK.equals(tag.getStyles().get(CssConstants.DISPLAY))) {
            return new BlockCssApplier();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Pass its instance as a parameter to `ConverterProperties` instance you use to convert the html:

```
converterProperties.setTagWorkerFactory(new StrongTagWorkerFactory())
```

And now just use this converterProperties to process your html:

```
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new File(htmlSource), new File(pdfOutput), converterProperties);
```

The resultant pdf looks as follows:
[image]